# How to add information about other tables to a buffer view in Postgresql?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, buffer

So basically I'm creating a view of a buffer that fulfills some conditions, and this buffer needs to have data from point attributes in another table

This is my query that doesn't work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW schema1.buffer_50_view AS 
SELECT a.siteid,
a.name,
sum(select count from schema2.point_table b where count >= 50 and 
st_dwithin(a.geom, b.geom, 100))  as sum_points,
st_buffer(p.geom, 100::double precision) AS buffer_50
FROM (select * from schema1.site_table p where site_progress = 100) a
```

it doesnt accept the sum line, and I have to add more lines like that, how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how big your data are, you might want to do this as a materialized view and refresh it on a schedule rather than as a view.

```
SELECT a.site_id, ST_Buffer(a.geom, 100) AS geom, count
FROM (
  SELECT sites.site_id, sites.geom, count(*) as count
  FROM schema1.site_table sites
  JOIN schema2.point_table pts
  ON ST_DWithin(sites.geom, pts.geom, 100)
  AND sites.site_progress = 100
  GROUP BY sites.site_id, sites.geom
  ) a
WHERE a.count > 50;
```

Comment: The query works, however something very strange is happening. select count(*) from schema1.site_table where site_progress = 100 returns a count of 2403 sites (all of them have unique ids). But the result of your query only returns 583 rows. Also another problem, you put the count at the end but I will need 3 different columns (sum of count where count <10, sum of count where count >=10 and < 50    and count >50)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

```
  SELECT 
  a.siteid,
  a.name,
  a._sumpoints
 FROM ( SELECT schema1.site_table.*,
 (SELECT count (*) as count FROM schema2.pointtable WHERE 
 st_dwithin(a.geom, st_buffer(b.geom, 100))) as sum_points
 FROM schema1.site_table
 order by sum_points) a
```

Test this then add a filter clause filter (`WHERE` put your definition of the filter) filter1

```
  SELECT 
  a.siteid,
  a.name,
  a._sumpoints

  FROM ( SELECT schema1.site_table.*,
  (SELECT count (*) as count FILTER (WHERE count>= 50) filter1 FROM 
  schema2.pointtable WHERE st_dwithin(a.geom, st_buffer(b.geom, 100))) 
  as sum_points
  FROM schema1.site_table
  order by sum_points) a
```

Comment: You're missing a FROM clause in your st dwithin, then you're missing the distance. Then the underscore is on the wrong position. Then the query was taking over 10minutes so had to cancel